# OpenCL result changes with arbitrary code alterations that are not related

Tags: c++, opencl

This is a very strange issue.  I'm working on an GPU based crypto miner and I have an issue with a SHA hash function.

1 - The initial function calls a SHA256 routine and then prints the results.  I'm comparing those results to a CPU based SHA256 to make sure I get the same thing.

2 - Later on in the function, there are other operations that occur, such as adding, XOR and additional SHA rounds.

As part of the miner kernel, I wrote an auxiliary function to decompose an array of 8 uints into an array of 32 unsigned char, using AND mask and bit shift.

I'm calling the kernel with global/local work unit of 1.

So, here's where things get really strange.  The part I am comparing is the very first SHA.  I get a buffer of 80 bytes in, SHA it and then print the result.  It matches under certain conditions.  However, if I make changes to the code that is executing AFTER that SHA executes, then it doesnt match.  This is what I've been able to narrow down:

1 - If I put a printf debug in the decomposition auxiliary function, the results match.  Just removing that printf causes it to mismatch.

2 - There are 4 operations I use to decompose the uint into char.  I tried lots of different ways to do this with the same result.  However, if I remove any 1 of the 4 "for" loops in the routine, it matches.  Simply removing a for loop in code that gets executed -after- the initial code, changes the result of the initial SHA.

3 - If I change my while loop to never execute then it matches. Again, this is all -after- the initial SHA comparison.

4 - If I remove all the calls to the auxiliary function, then it matches.  Simply calling the function after the initial SHA causes a mismatch.

I've tried adding memory guards everywhere, however being that its 1 global and 1 local work unit, I don't see how that could apply.

I'd love to debug this, but apparently openCL cannot be debugged in VS 2019 (really?)

Any thoughts, guesses, insight would be appreciated.

Thanks!

```
    inline void loadUintHash ( __global unsigned char* dest, __global uint* src) {

      //**********if I remove this it doesn't work
printf ("src1 %08x%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x",
src[0],
src[1],
src[2],
src[3],
src[4],
src[5],
src[6],
src[7]
);
    
//**********if I take away any one of these 4 for loops, then it works
    for ( int i = 0; i < 8; i++) 
        dest[i*4+3] = (src[i] & 0xFF000000) >> 24;

    for ( int i = 0; i < 8; i++) 
        dest[i*4+2] = (src[i] & 0x00FF0000) >> 16;
        
    for ( int i = 0; i < 8; i++) 
        dest[i*4+1] = (src[i] & 0x0000FF00) >> 8;
               
    for ( int i = 0; i < 8; i++) 
        dest[i*4] = (src[i] & 0x000000FF);
        

      //**********if I remove this it doesn't work
printf ("src2 %08x%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x",
src[0],
src[1],
src[2],
src[3],
src[4],
src[5],
src[6],
src[7]
);


}

#define HASHOP_ADD 0
#define HASHOP_XOR 1
#define HASHOP_SHA_SINGLE 2
#define HASHOP_SHA_LOOP 3
#define HASHOP_MEMGEN 4
#define HASHOP_MEMADD 5
#define HASHOP_MEMXOR 6
#define HASHOP_MEM_SELECT 7
#define HASHOP_END 8

__kernel void dyn_hash (__global uint* byteCode, __global uint* memGenBuffer, int memGenSize, __global uint* hashResult, __global char* foundFlag, __global unsigned char* header, __global unsigned char* shaScratch) {
    
    int computeUnitID = get_global_id(0);

    __global uint* myMemGen = &memGenBuffer[computeUnitID * memGenSize * 8];        //each memGen unit is 256 bits, or 8 bytes
    __global uint* myHashResult = &hashResult[computeUnitID * 8];
    __global char* myFoundFlag = foundFlag + computeUnitID;
    __global unsigned char* myHeader = header + (computeUnitID * 80);
    __global unsigned char* myScratch = shaScratch + (computeUnitID * 32);


    sha256 ( computeUnitID, 80, myHeader, myHashResult );

    //**********this is the result I am comparing
    if (computeUnitID == 0) {
       printf ("gpu first sha uint  %08x%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x",
                myHashResult[0],
                myHashResult[1],
                myHashResult[2],
                myHashResult[3],
                myHashResult[4],
                myHashResult[5],
                myHashResult[6],
                myHashResult[7]
                );
    }


    uint linePtr = 0;
    uint done = 0;
    uint currentMemSize = 0;
    uint instruction = 0;

//**********if I change this to done == 1, then it works
    while (done == 0) {

        if (byteCode[linePtr] == HASHOP_ADD) {
            linePtr++;
            uint arg1[8];
            for ( int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                arg1[i] = byteCode[linePtr+i];
            linePtr += 8;
        }


        else if (byteCode[linePtr] == HASHOP_XOR) {
            linePtr++;
            uint arg1[8];
            for ( int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                arg1[i] = byteCode[linePtr+i];
            linePtr += 8;
        }


        else if (byteCode[linePtr] == HASHOP_SHA_SINGLE) {
            linePtr++;
        }


        else if (byteCode[linePtr] == HASHOP_SHA_LOOP) {
            printf ("HASHOP_SHA_LOOP");
            linePtr++;
            uint loopCount = byteCode[linePtr];

            
            for ( int i = 0; i < loopCount; i++) {

                loadUintHash(myScratch, myHashResult);

                sha256 ( computeUnitID, 32, myScratch, myHashResult );

                


                
                            if (computeUnitID == 1)     {
                loadUintHash(myScratch, myHashResult);

... more irrelevant code...


This is how the kernel is being called:

    size_t globalWorkSize = 1;// computeUnits;
    size_t localWorkSize = 1;
    returnVal = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL, &globalWorkSize, &localWorkSize, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: If for 1 global work item it doesn't work then very likely it won't work on cpu either. Transform opencl kernel code into plain C (just remove OpenCL specifics) and run it on cpu.

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up being multiple things.  1 - The CPU SHA had a bug in it that was causing an incorrect result in some cases.  2 - There was a very strange syntax error which seems to have broken the compiler in a weird way:

void otherproc () {
...do stuff...
}

if (something) {/
...other code
}

That forward slash after the opening curly brace was messing up "otherproc" in a weird way, and the compiler did not throw an error.  After staring at the code line by line I found that slash, removed it, and everything started working.

If anyone is interested, the working implementation of a GPU miner can be found here:

https://github.com/dynamofoundation/dyn_miner